# How query-replace-regexp for all text exact before specific text?

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace

emacs 26.1, windows 10

I have some text. I need to replace all text before `WARN`

[image]

I use:

1. query-replace-regexp: .*WARN
2. query replace regexp: RET

But I need to delete all text BEFORE **WARN**.
How I can do this?

here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole line up to the WARN?

Comment: @A_P Yes , I want to delete whole line BEFORE word WARN

Comment: may I suggest few alternative solutions:
1. You can define a keyboard macro as follows: C-x ( C-s WARN Ent M-b C-Space C-a C-w C-x ) This will give a macro that does what you need for first occurring line with WARN. Then just C-u 50 C-x e to do the same macro 50 times. 
2. install multiple-cursors (and you should anyways) select WARN and then do mc/select-next-like-this (bind it to something easy) keep selecting and then just edit all lines with WARN as if you were editing a single line.

Comment: @A_P I known about multi cursors. I use them. But I want to solve this task by regexp.

Comment: emacs must be doing something under the covers. none of these solutions work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013124/regex-matching-up-to-the-first-occurrence-of-a-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the text before `WARN`, just enter `WARN` as the replacement text. That is, use `WARN` as your input to the second prompt.

Comment: @A_P: I don't understand; sorry.

Comment: *WARN does not work. Try it, you'll see. I don't understand how the answer got accepted.

Comment: `.*WARN`, not `*WARN`.

Comment: blind as a bat. Sorry for the confusion. It does the job.

Comment: @A_P: No problem; and thanks for confirming. A prefix of `.` is very easy to not notice.